# C# Algorithm to determine grouping of people based on a value

Tags: c#, grouping

I'm attempting to write an algorithm that creates groups of people based on their 'score'. 
A person has two paramaters, a name and a score. (The range of the score is between -10 and 10 but that's really not relevant) I'm looking to create groups with equal numbers of people (if possible based on the number of people presented) where the average score of the group members is the same (or very close to the same).

For example:

Group 1 (Average Score=2)
 -- John Doe, Score 2
 -- Jane Doe, Score 7
 -- Jack Black, Score -3

Group 2 (Average Score=2)
 -- Bobby Flay, Score 4
 -- Cary Page, Score -3
 -- Linus Tarval, Score 5

Comment: How many groups? Also, how many people will you have?

Comment: The number of groups is infinite, but the number of people will always be selected by the user. The number of people per group will also be provided by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This smells like a variation of the classical [Partition Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem), which is NP-Hard although some heuristics exists. You can have a loot at wikipedia page.. probably a greedy approach would work in your case.

You should try to fill your groups by choosing the right group to place a specific person, probably by starting with having them ordered by score.

Comment: Thanks Jack, the "greedy approach" worked well enough for this application.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough problem.  The best you will probably do is a heuristic, but k-means is a good one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering